# Bootstrap carousel indicator is not active

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap carousel with the indicators like this

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li class="carousel-icon" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li class="carousel-icon" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
  <li class="carousel-icon" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
  <li class="carousel-icon" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3" class=""></li>
  <li class="carousel-icon" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4" class=""></li>
 </ol>
```

The active class on the first indicator doesn't change the icon to active.

Answer (score 0):

The href in the controls must be the same as the ID in the carousel.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue after battling it for an hour I have come to know I was using an extra heading inside `<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">`. Like below

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<h3>Some absolute positioned div above all slides - this was causing issue</h3>
<div class="item">
...
</div>
<div class="item">
...
</div>
<div class="item">
...
</div>
</div>
```

**Additionally on clicking back from first slide showed empty slide for me.**

Please make sure if you are using any of such heading / div etc other than `<div class="item">` it will cause such issues. I hope it will help and will save sometime :)

Answer (score -1):

You only posted part of the Bootstrap carousel. Here is the sample code documented at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel If you are still not getting the results expected check Devtools. There may be a class being inherited causing the issue perhaps.

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```